airflow command error: the following arguments are required: GROUP_OR_COMMAND как пофиксить?
При запуске контейнера airflow с помощью docker desctop для виндовса, возникает ошибка airflow command error: the following arguments are required: GROUP_OR_COMMAND, see help above.
Как пофиксить?

